# I have array of string i want to pass one by one string to sql query to get required column

Tags: java, sql

[QA01, ATC, WCOCO, WZR3, SCAL] this is the array of string I have. I want to pass to sql query to retrieve columns (Release_name,cycle_name,BG_bu_id).I  want to pass the same query in Java code. Please help me with the query if you have any idea.

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Please post your code, context and frameworks.

Comment: This question is impossible to decipher.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

let's say this is all your arguments to be passed for query stored in array....

```
String[] arguments = new String[]{"QA01", "ATC", "WCOCO", "WZR3", "SCAL"};
for(int i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
      //your query code
    result[i] = "select Release_name,cycle_name,BG_bu_id from <Table Name> where <column_name> ="+arguments[i];
}
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, if I declare all my array elements then it will be like hard coding.If tomorrow table data change,I may get some array element more than 5.then again need to hard code this.

Comment: Hi Ravi, if I declare all my array elements then it will be like hard coding.If tomorrow table data change,I may get some array element more than 5.then again need to hard code this. is there any alternative that we can pass array dynamically.So that if tomorrow my element increases also query will run.I no need to hard code it

Comment: @RAKESHNAYAK hi.. Well you haven't mentioned from where you are getting those array elements... i mean if you can give me some more information then i may be able to help you...

You always can get those array elements dynamically... using queries or any other alternative methods..